# Batch convert PDFs to CSVs

Tags: python, csv, tabula

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code that I attempted:

```
import glob
import tabula

for filepath in glob.iglob('C:/Users/username/Downloads/folder with space/myfolderwithpdfs/*.pdf'):
    tabula.convert_into(filepath, pages="all", output_format='csv')
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 6>()
      5 # transform the pdfs into excel files
      6 for filepath in glob.iglob(C:/Users/username/Downloads/folder with space/myfolderwithpdfs/*.pdf'):
----> 7     tabula.convert_into(filepath, pages="all", output_format='csv')

TypeError: convert_into() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_path'
```

Comment: The error says you need to add an output path. `convert_into(filepath, "c:/Users/usernamme/where-i-want-output", pages="all", output_format='csv')` may suffice.

Comment: careful with the tags you use, just hit the specific ones you need :)

Comment: @tdelaney
getting error :

Error from tabula-java:
Error: Cannot create file C:\Users\username\Downloads\new Folder with CSvs

Comment: @Umar.H forgive me I'm using jupyter-notebook and did use pandas

Comment: no problem, but it has no bearing on your question or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the pdf files in your Download folder then convert it into tabular using csv format.

```
import os
import glob
import tabula

path="/Users/username/Downloads/"
for filepath in glob.glob(path+'*.pdf'):
    name=os.path.basename(filepath)
    tabula.convert_into(input_path=filepath, 
                        output_path=path+name+".csv",
                        pages="all")
```

Comment: Thank you, question can decide how the data is being converted, for example the pdf has data in two columns but when converted some data is being merged with another column

Comment: that is a limitation of tabula where it merges two columns into one.

Comment: ok, is there any other way to do such conversion without having that limitation?

Comment: Can I add an encoding type to this?

Answer (score 0):

it appears you have not defined the output_path location for your converted pdf

> import glob import tabula
>
> for filepath in glob.iglob('C:/Users/username/Downloads/folder with
> space/myfolderwithpdfs/*.pdf'):
> tabula.convert_into(filepath, pages="all", output_format='csv', output_path="C:/Users/username/Downloads/new Folder with CSvs")

Comment: getting error :

Error from tabula-java:
Error: Cannot create file C:\Users\username\Downloads\new Folder with CSvs